# Modulation by a tritone: nomenclature

Tags: chord-progressions

The chord progression in question follows:

C -> C#7 -> F#

in order to modulate from F to F# (C is the V of F etc.)

But is it F# or Gb? And if it's Gb, should the C#7 be a Db7 instead?

Does it matter??

Comment: it doesn't matter. You may have Eb-instruments that will play Eb major and Bb playing Ab, but the C-instruments play F#. Regularly the Dominant of F# is C#7 but even if you notate Db7 one who is able to read or play in F# major wouldn't mind if the V7 is written as Db7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way, you'll end up with either 6 ♯ or 6 ♭.It will be more dependant on what key(s) any other instruments, which may be transposing,  may need to be written in.